# Angular send POST request with resource service to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I´m trying to send a POST request using a resource service in Angular to a Rails API. Both, angular client and API are not in same server (so there is Cross Domain).

I´m not able to send the request, and I think probably I have more than one problem (I think the angular controller or service are wrong) and probably I have a problem with CSRF (cross domain).

I have read a lot of posts, and have added some suggestions, so now, I have a mix of all, that is not working.

**For CSRF purpose**:

1. In rails I have added :

   - Application controller:

     ```
     class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base        

      protect_from_forgery

     after_filter  :set_csrf_cookie_for_ng

      def set_csrf_cookie_for_ng
       cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?
      end

      protected

      def verified_request?
        super || form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X_XSRF_TOKEN']
      end  
     end
     ```
2. In angular:

   - app.js:

     `angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.i18n']).
     config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

     $routeProvider.when('/boat-booking', {templateUrl: 'partials/boat-booking.html', controller: 'BoatBookingCtrl'});
     $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
     delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];

     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
     }]);`

For sending the POST request purpose:

I have a controller with a variable I want to send:

```
.controller('BusinessCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Business) {

        $scope.createBusiness = function() {
            //var business = {name: "business1"};
            alert ("business:" + $scope.business);  
            alert ("businessName:" + $scope.business.name);  // This is showing the business name, so the value is in scope.
            $scope.business = Business.save($scope.business);                       
        };
    });
```

Service:

```
  .factory('Business', 

      function($resource){          
        var businesses =
         $resource('http://127.0.0.1\\:3000/:business', {}, {       
            query: {method:'GET', params:{business:'businesses'}, isArray: true},
            save: {method:'POST', params:{business:'businesses'}, isArray: false}
         });        
         return businesses;           
      }
  );
```

When I execute this, I get:

```
Started OPTIONS "/businesses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-04 10:41:20 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/businesses"):
```

in rails log. I have tried other combinations with different error messages but none of them worked.

Thanks,
Rober.

**UPDATE**

if I remove the parameters from angular service call in controller, like:

```
$scope.business = Business.save();
```

Then, the logs in Rails change. Now, I send a POST request instead of OPTIONS. But, I have some other errors...

```
Started POST "/businesses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-04 11:00:31 +0100
Processing by BusinessesController#create as HTML
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Businesses_controller.create!!!!!
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how I solved it in this post.

[Sending an Angular post request with parameter to Rails API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772852/sending-an-angular-post-request-with-parameter-to-rails-api)

Regards,
Roberto.